# Setting border on <col> on a HTML table with Angular conditional classes doesn't work on Safari

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, safari

I'm trying to make a column of a simple HTML table feel like *selected* by giving it a border whenever a user clicks on a th element using angular :

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core' ;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectionArray = [false, false, false];

  changeSelection(index: number): void {
    this.selectionArray = this.selectionArray.map(() => false);
    this.selectionArray[index] = true;
  }
}
```

app.component.html :

```
<table border="1px" cellspacing="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col [class.selected]="selectionArray[0] === true">
    <col [class.selected]="selectionArray[1] === true">
    <col [class.selected]="selectionArray[2] === true">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th (click)="changeSelection(0)">Firstname</th>
      <th (click)="changeSelection(1)">Lastname</th>
      <th (click)="changeSelection(2)">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

app.component.css :

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.selected {
    border: 2px double yellowgreen;
}
```

The sample above was generated and built with angular cli 7 and works flawlessly on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. But on Safari (12) there are some strange behaviors. first of all, if I change the border of .selected class to 1px, it doesn't draw a border around column at all. But even ignoring that, Only the first time a column is selected, it gets bordered and Safari ignores other clicks on th' s unless I somehow force Safari to resize the window (by zooming out/in, changing the size of developer console, resizing window manually , etc).

Is there anything I can do?